# How to getText the multiple EditText value in android using For Loop

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, arrays

In My App i have 10 Edittext and 10 TextView

I have created instance for the both EditText and TextView like

```
String[] messageText=new String[10];
String[] messageEdit=new String[10];
TextView oTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common1_EditText);
    TextView oTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common2_EditText);
    TextView oTextView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common3_EditText);
    TextView oTextView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common4_EditText);
    TextView oTextView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common5_EditText);
    TextView oTextView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common6_EditText);
    TextView oTextView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common7_EditText);
    TextView oTextView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common8_EditText);
    TextView oTextView9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common9_EditText);
    TextView oTextView10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common10_EditText);

    EditText oEditTextHiden1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon1_EditText);
    EditText oEditTextHiden2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon2_EditText);
    EditText oEditTextHiden3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon3_EditText);
    EditText oEditTextHiden4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon4_EditText);
    EditText oEditTextHiden5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon5_EditText);
    EditText oEditTextHiden6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon6_EditText);
    EditText oEditTextHiden7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon7_EditText);
    EditText oEditTextHiden8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon8_EditText);
    EditText oEditTextHiden9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon9_EditText);
    EditText oEditTextHiden10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon10_EditText);
```

now i need to get all the TextView getText() and EditText getText()

I have try some method but it is not working

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        messageText[i] = (oTextView+i).getText().toString();//it says oTextView cannot be resolved to a variable
        messageEdit[i] = (oEditTextHiden+i).getText().toString();
      }
      Log.i("message", "message :"+Arrays.deepToString(messageText)+" "+Arrays.deepToString(messageEdit));
```

Comment: put all `oTextView` on one `List<TextView>` and work with that

Comment: You have to create two array-lists one for text-view and other for Edit-text and then work with that.

Comment: can i have any sample

Comment: Try changing `(oTextView+i)` to `("oTextView"+i)`

Comment: @gilonm i have tried it it is not working

Comment: Can you post the xml file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store the ids of the `EditText` and loop over them, since the View ids are integers, you can do that easily like so :

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.editText1,R.id.editText2,R.id.editText3};//and so on

for(int id : ids){
    EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(id);
    values.add(t.getText().toString());
}
```

Or if you only want the text and don't want to do anything else with the `EditText` view itself, you could make it in one line this:

```
for(int id : ids) values.add(((EditText)findViewById(id)).getText().toString());
```

Comment: That's what i am talk in about! +1 up

Comment: You can also use something like: `EditText text = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("generalname" + number, "id", context.getPackageName()));`

Comment: @Ayoub according to the docs: Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

Comment: Your missing a bracket. Should be: values.add(t.getText().toString());

Answer (score 3):

Add all TextView and EdiText in Array Like this

```
TextView[] oTextView = { oTextView1, oTextView2, oTextView3,
            oTextView4, oTextView5, oTextView6, oTextView7, oTextView8,
            oTextView9, oTextView10 };

EditText[] oEditTextHiden = { oEditTextHiden1, oEditTextHiden2,
            oEditTextHiden3, oEditTextHiden4, oEditTextHiden5,
            oEditTextHiden6, oEditTextHiden7, oEditTextHiden8,
            oEditTextHiden9, oEditTextHiden10 };
```

Then `getText()` Should look like this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        messageText[i] = oTextView[i].getText().toString();
        messageEdit[i] = oEditTextHiden[i].getText().toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] messageText=new String[10];
String[] messageEdit=new String[10];
TextView[] textViews = new TextView[10];
textViews[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common1_EditText);
textViews[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common2_EditText);
textViews[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common3_EditText);
textViews[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common4_EditText);
textViews[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common5_EditText);
textViews[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common6_EditText);
textViews[6] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common7_EditText);
textViews[7] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common8_EditText);
textViews[8] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common9_EditText);
textViews[9] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common10_EditText);

EditText[] editTexts = new EditText[10];
editTexts[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon1_EditText);
editTexts[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon2_EditText);
editTexts[2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon3_EditText);
editTexts[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon4_EditText);
editTexts[4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon5_EditText);
editTexts[5] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon6_EditText);
editTexts[6] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon7_EditText);
editTexts[7] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon8_EditText);
editTexts[8] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon9_EditText);
editTexts[9] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Hidencommon10_EditText);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    messageText[i] = textViews[i].getText().toString();
    messageEdit[i] = editTexts[i].getText().toString();
  }
  Log.i("message", "message :"+Arrays.deepToString(messageText)+" "+Arrays.deepToString(messageEdit));
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the tag associated with the textview.

For example :

In Xml you need to create TextView and editText as following :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/llParent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="tv1"
    android:text="TextView1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="et1"
    android:text="EditText1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="tv2"
    android:text="TextView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="et2"
    android:text="EditText2" />

  ===== Similarly 10 Textviews and EditTexts========

</LinearLayout>
```

In Code :

```
String[] messageText = new String[10];
String[] messageEdit = new String[10];

LinearLayout llParent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llParent);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        messageText[i - 1] = ((TextView) llParent.findViewWithTag("tv" + i))
                .getText().toString();
        messageEdit[i - 1] = ((EditText) llParent.findViewWithTag("et" + i))
                .getText().toString();
    }
```

Happy Coding.... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This :-

```
    ArrayList<TextView> arrayListTextViews = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    TextView oTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common1_EditText);
    TextView oTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common2_EditText);
    TextView oTextView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common3_EditText);
    TextView oTextView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common4_EditText);
    TextView oTextView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common5_EditText);
    TextView oTextView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common6_EditText);
    TextView oTextView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common7_EditText);
    TextView oTextView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common8_EditText);
    TextView oTextView9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common9_EditText);
    TextView oTextView10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_common10_EditText);
    arrayListTextViews.add(oTextView1);
    arrayListTextViews.add(oTextView2);
    arrayListTextViews.add(oTextView3);
    arrayListTextViews.add(oTextView4);
    arrayListTextViews.add(oTextView5);
    arrayListTextViews.add(oTextView6);
    arrayListTextViews.add(oTextView7);
    arrayListTextViews.add(oTextView8);
    arrayListTextViews.add(oTextView9);
    arrayListTextViews.add(oTextView10);
```

and then access textviews from arrayListTextViews in the loop.
Also do the same for Your Edittext.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use the `getIdentifier` method in the `Resources` class

something like that

```
messageText[i] = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("Tab_common"+i+"_EditText", "id", context.getPackageName()));
messageEdit[i] = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("Tab_Hidencommon"+i+"_EditText", "id", context.getPackageName()));
```

Comment: getIdentifier Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name. (From the docs)

Comment: I know it is less efficient, but it's 1 time initialization is not a problem and avoids having to keep track of all those IDs.